# tinyMCE replaces whole form not only textarea

Tags: java, web-applications, tinymce, tiles, freemarker

I'm building a webapp (using java,spring,freemarker and tiles) with tinyMCE editor.

I've added all files to classpath, everything is on the right place, tinyMCE editor is ALMOST correctly loaded...

There are several fields in my form, text inputs, options, buttons, labels etc... but the problem occurs when I run this form. tinyMCE replaces the whole form, not just textarea and puts that form inside itself - into tinyMCE editor area.

I am following basic installation found here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation
My code is almost the same as here, has more elements in form.

Is there any solution for this? Is this a standard behavior?

I run it on FF 13.0.1 if it matters...

my init code in form.ftl file is:

```
<#import "../spring.ftl" as spring>
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            height : "480",
            mode : "textareas"
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <@form.form>
            <input type="text" id="title"/><br>
            <input type="text" id="author"/><br>
            <textarea id="content"></textarea><br>
            <button type="submit"/> <button type="reset"/>
        </@form.form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to answer your question please post your full tinymce initialization (i guess the error is there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok

I've found the solution. The problem was that I had two elements with the same **id="content"**, there was

```
<div id="content">...</div>
```

and

```
<textarea id="content"></textarea>
```

when I changed it to be unique it resolved the problem.